# Event listener does not get called for elements that were added to the DOM later through a script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had an original HTML, say, like so:

```
<tr>
  <td class = 'greatTD' id = 'great1'>I am too great to be anything less.</td>
</tr>
```

Then I added an element through JavaScript like so:

```
function AddStuff()
{
    var s = '<tr><td class = "greatTD" id = "great2">I am even greater.</td></tr>';

    $('#foo').after(s);
}

function WireHandlers()
{
    $('.greatTD').click(GreatTDClickHandler);
}

function GreatTDClickHandler()
{
    // not being called for #great2
    // how do I make it be called?
}

$(document).ready(function() { WireHandlers(); });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: @NickTomlin Thank you. That was relevant.

Answer (score 3):

The event handler is being assigned on load, before the `.greatTD` elements exist. Therefore you need to use a delegate handler, like this:

```
function WireHandlers() {
    $('#foo').on('click', '.greatTD', GreatTDClickHandler);
}
```

This attaches the event to the `#foo` element, which is present on load, and then filters it so that it's only executed on click of the `.greatTD` element.

Comment: Wouldn't the `.greatTD` selector not find the element since it is inserted after `#foo`?

Comment: @Danny not at all, as it's interpreted when the element is clicked.

Comment: Thanks, @RoryMcCrossan. What if the selector was not id-based like `#foo` but was a pseudo-selector like `table td tr:last`?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 that would work too, so long as the element selected is a parent of `.greatTD`. Ideally, it should be the closest parent which is available on page load.

Comment: That's because the appended `tr` is not a child of `#foo`. Change it to `table` and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/cqbuR/1/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan but isn't that what he is doing with the `$('#foo').after(s)`? Doesn't he want the click handler to work on `s`? I guess his example isn't big enough to get all the details...

Comment: Sorry for all the confusion. I just threw the `#foo` bit in to say that it is just *any* element. I did not want to suggest structure with regard to that selector.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work.

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.greatTD', GreatTDClickHandler );
```

**[jQuery .on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

Comment: Thank you very much, Danny. This, too, worked for me.